# Update Python with APT

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, python, dependencies

I installed python3.10 to my Ubuntu 20.04 using the deadsnakes PPA. It worked fine, and python3.8 is still my system's python3:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.10
```

However when I try to upgrade system packages using apt, it now throws an error:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is installed
 libpython3.10-dev : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is installed
 python3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is installed
 python3.10-minimal : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Following the advice from above doesn't help:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded.
14 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2 566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 68,6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Д/н] y
(Reading database ... 200427 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) ..
.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10
.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu
.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) .
..
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.1
0.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py', which is also in package l
ibpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Neither an attempt to uninstall python3.10 does:

```
$ sudo apt purge python3.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is to be installed
 libpython3.10-dev : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is to be installed
 python3.10-dev : Depends: python3.10 (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but it is not going to be installed
 python3.10-minimal : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is to be installed
                      Recommends: python3.10 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: The deadsnakes PPA has bad packaging and conflicts in it.  This is a problem with the PPA and needs fixed by the PPA maintainers.

Comment: @ThomasWard thank you for reply. Does it mean that either `apt upgrade` or `apt --fix-broken install` will work right after they fix the dependencies in the repository? Or will I continue to get those errors until I do something else in my OS?

Comment: the problem is that the two packages are trying to install on top of each other - one for python3.10's standard libs and one for the minimal libs which both contain the same files.  You can't uninstall either because you need to remove the other dependent packages (all the python 3.10 files you manually installed).  However, because the libpython3-stdlib and libpython3.10-minimal install some of the *same files* you can't remove one without resulting in "file not found" for the other's removal, and vice versa. (1/2_

Comment: Upstream PPA maintainer has to fix the packaging so ONE of those packages touches the file and not the other, then removal should function properly.  Failing that we have to manually remove all python3.10 components - `apt purge {lib,}python3.10{,-dev,-minimal}` and *manually* erase the entirety of Python 3.10 unless other packages are dependent on it as well.  (2/2)

Comment: @ThomasWard thank you! With a similar command I've deleted python3.10 and managed to update the rest of the packages in the system: `sudo apt purge {lib,}python3.10{,-dev,-minimal} libpython3.10-stdlib`. Somehow some of python3.10 components were left out and upgraded lately with `sudo apt upgrade` and were deleted manually after that: `apt purge python3.10-distutils python3.10-lib2to3`.

Comment: glad to see it helped, I added some changes to the command I provided to include the missing libraries, etc. that you indicated with a similar command.  This *should* work in the answer now, and you can mark it as accepted to indicate this question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the installation of the two Python 3.10 versions from the Deadsnakes PPA fails is because there's conflicts in the packaging that should never happen.  Unfortunately, that's something the PPA maintainers have to fix, and not something we can fix.

You did ask how to *remove* Python 3.10 from the PPA as well, so I'll give you the instructions on how to do that.

You can clear out all the Python 3.10 bits from the PPA with this command:

```
sudo apt purge {lib,}python3.10{,-dev,-minimal} libpython3.10-stdlib python3.10{-distutils,-lib2to3}
```

That will *remove* Python 3.10 that was installed via the Deadsnakes PPA completely.  (DO NOT do this if you are on Ubuntu 22.04 and using the standard system Python, ONLY do this if you are using 20.04 or another supported Ubuntu and the Deadsnakes PPA to get Python 3.10)

Comment: Do you have advice on how to fix the problem if you are on Ubuntu 22.04 because you upgraded, but the upgrade kept the deadsnakes PPA and that version of Python 3.10 (i.e. Version: 3.10.8-1+focal1)?